# Existing T4 database helpers for DB schema retrieval

Tags: database, t4

Do you know any T4 template which would provide me with basic DB schema methods and properties (`GetTables`, `GetColumns`, `MapSqlTypesToClr`, etc.)?

I know it's easy to retrieve that information, but there are a lot of extra helper functions around it, so why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

You probably got this already but I'll leave here a possible solution.

SubSonic 3 uses T4 for code generation, its db inspector should be more than enough for you.
Have a look at: http://subsonicproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where's the place for T4 in all that, but you can try [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby): it can perform database schema reverse-engineering and return a nice [Schema](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/source/browse/trunk/src/octalforty.Wizardby.Core/SemanticModel/Schema.cs) object with all tables and columns. As for mapping `DbType`s to CLR types, you'll need an appropriate `IDbTypeMapper` (I think [SqlServer2005TypeMapper](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/source/browse/trunk/src/octalforty.Wizardby.Db/SqlServer2005/SqlServer2005TypeMapper.cs) will do).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a T4 template that dumps a schema to a c# static class library that may do what you are trying to accomplish:
[codepaste.net snippet](http://codepaste.net/b1geac)

I couldn't paste the code here because the syntax highlighter doesn't like T4 tags (who does?).

This will allow you to get the column name like so:

```
string columnName= dbSchema.Tables.Products.Columns.QuantityPerUnit.ColumnName;
```